# SQL: How to select a single row based on a column matched against multiple possible values with preferred match order?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Using MariaDB.

Say you have a table, one of the columns is `color` and is the primary key so it's unique.

I want a select statement to get one row based on color but i want to search for three possible color matches in a preferred order.

A normal `WHERE color='red' OR color='blue' OR color='green'` won't work because that would return multiple rows. I can't use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` because the three search values are not alphabetical.

I want to search for `color='red'` and if there is a red give me just that one row. If there is no red then give me the row that `color='blue'`. If there are no red or blue then give me the row with `color='green'`. But just to be clear, when searching for the first color red, even if there is a blue and green only return the red because its the preferred match. But if no red then down the line for the next color blue.

I looked at `if()`, `IF...THEN` and `CASE` and didn't see how to do this. Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `ORDER BY` clause and `LIMIT 1`:

```
WHERE color='red' OR color='blue' OR color='green'
ORDER BY color='red' DESC, 
         color='blue' DESC,
         color='green' DESC -- not actually needed
LIMIT 1;
```

MySql and Mariadb evaluate boolean expressions like `color='red'` as 1 for `true` and `0` for `false`, so when you sort by `color='red' DESC` the row that returns 1 (the row with `color='red'`) will be on top and all the others next.

Or, use a `CASE` expression:

```
WHERE color='red' OR color='blue' OR color='green'
ORDER BY CASE color
  WHEN 'red' THEN 1
  WHEN 'blue' THEN 2
  WHEN 'green' THEN 3
END
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Both answers (order by vs union) look doable and im not sure which has better performance. However i like better how the order by looks and im assuming order by is less work than unions so i will go with this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select *
from (
    select *, 1 as Rank from MyTable where color = 'red'
    union all
    select *, 2 as Rank from MyTable where color = 'blue'
    union all
    select *, 3 as Rank from MyTable where color = 'green'
) x
order by Rank
limit 1
```